# How do I get `sbt test` to recognize my custom target?

Tags: scala, sbt

Using `sbt 0.13.7`, I am setting `target := new File("sbt-target")` in my `build.sbt` file. This appropriately sets the compiler to output all class files to `./sbt-target/scala-2.11/{test-,}classes`. That is fine, but when I invoke `sbt test`), the JVM is unable to find my source files:

```
> test
[error] (test:executeTests) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load class: com.spingo.api.test.presenter.EventSummaryPresenterSpec
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 28, 2014 3:41:27 PM
```

(however, it works for `sbt test:console`)

```
> test:console
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'SpinGo Releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Class.forName("com.spingo.api.test.presenter.EventSummaryPresenterSpec")
res0: Class[_] = class com.spingo.api.test.presenter.EventSummaryPresenterSpec
```

I'm flabbergasted.

My higher goal is I'm trying to get `scala-ide` to use a different folder for compiled artifacts than `sbt`. This is another issue, but the compiler under `scala-ide` ignores the `<classpathentry output="..."` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a patch to `sbt` which fixes the issue I am seeing; also, I've described the issue in further depth here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1701

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same issue.

You need to set your target directory relative to your base project directory. Replace:

```
target := new File("sbt-target")
```

With:

```
target := baseDirectory.value / "sbt-target"
```